# Pandas apply multiple function with list

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply

I have a df with a 'File_name' column which contains strings of a file name, which I would like to parse:

```
data = [['f1h3_13oct2021_gt1.csv',  2], ['p8-gfr-20dec2021-81.csv', 0.5]]
df= pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['File_name', 'Result'])
df.head()
```

Now I would like to create a new column where I parse the file name with '_' and '-' delimiters and then search in resulting list for the string that I could transform in datetime object. The name convention is not always the same (different order, so I cannot rely on string characters location) and the code should include a "try" conversion to datetime, as often the piece of string which should be the date is either in the wrong format or missing.
I came up with the following, but it does not really look pythonic to me

```
# Solution #1
for i, value in df['File_name'].iteritems():
    chunks = value.split('-') + value.split('_')
    for chunk in chunks:
         try:
            df.loc[i,'Date_Sol#1'] = dt.datetime.strptime(chunk, '%d%b%Y')
         except:
            pass
df.head()
```

Alternative, I was trying to use the apply method with the two functions I really cannot think a way to solve the two functions chained and the try - pass statement, but I really did not manage to get it working

```
# Solution #2
import re
splitme = lambda x: re.split('_|-', x)
calcdate = lambda x : dt.datetime.strptime(x, '%d%b%Y') 
df['t1'] = df['File_name'].apply(splitme)
df['Date_Sol#2'] =df['t1'].apply(lambda x: calcdate(x) for x in df['t1'] if isinstance(calcdate(x),dt.datetime) else Pass)

df.head()
```

I thought a list comprehension might help?
Any help how Solution #2 might look like?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to extract and convert the possible chunks as date, you could [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) the string on delimiters, [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) to multiple rows and attempt to convert to date with [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df.join(pd
 .to_datetime(df['File_name']
              .str.split(r'[_-]')
              .explode(), errors='coerce')
 .dropna().rename('Date')
)
```

output:

```
                 File_name  Result       Date
0   f1h3_13oct2021_gt1.csv     2.0 2021-10-13
1  p8-gfr-20dec2021-81.csv     0.5 2021-12-20
```

*NB. if you have potentially many dates per string, you need to add a further step to select the one you want. Please give more details if this is the case.*

###### python version for old pandas

```
import re
s = pd.Series([next(iter(pd.to_datetime(re.split(r'[._-]', s), errors='coerce')
                           .dropna()), float('nan'))
               for s in df['File_name']], index=df.index, name='date')

df.join(s)
```

Comment: Hi mozway, thanks for your answer.
No, it will always be only one date per string. However I tried your code and it gets the following error:
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'explode'

Comment: working with Python 2.7,13 and pandas 0.23.3

Comment: This is a very old pandas version, can you update? Also python2.7 is end of life.

Comment: I know...but unfortunately it does not depend on me and is company policy. Any hint on how to do that with lambda functions?

Comment: @ingcerullo please try the alternative

Comment: it works now, but I had to add format = '%d%b%Y'. Thanks!

Comment: @ingcerullo you're welcome! You can consider accepting the answer if your problem is solved